# youtube directe lite can't upload videos to only one uniqe account

Tags: youtube-api

to let other users record and upload videos to my youtube playlist i used Youtube Directe Lite, the probleme is the videos are uploaded to user's account instead of my account.

did i missed any configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's what YT Direct Lite is for. But then you can moderate all those submitted videos on http://ytdirectlite.appspot.com/static-min/admin.html

Once you accept the videos, they will appear on your playlist, but at the end videos will actually be hosted on the uploader's account.

YouTube strongly recommends to let your users to upload to their account, rather than letting them upload any video to your channel.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, i completely forgot about the /admin.html part. now after the videos is approved its uploaded to my playlist.